# Excel VBA Script to consolidate rows from multiple tabs into one based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Workbook consisting of multiple sheets that are all structured the same. I want to consolidate all the Data where in Column 238 it says "Yes" to a summary worksheet. Ideally it would only copy certain columns instead of the complete row where this criteria is met.

I have this code as a basis:

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Add a new summary worksheet.
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the 
' summary worksheet.
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)

        ' Specify the range to place the data.
        Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

        ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
        ' worksheet to copy all the data.
        If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
               "summary worksheet to place the data."
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        ' This statement copies values and formats from each 
        ' worksheet.
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

        ' Optional: This statement will copy the sheet 
        ' name in the H column.
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

This is copying the whole worksheet. I would like to implement that only certain rows that match the criteria get copied from each sheet.

Edit: To be more clear, the code above is some code I found. I want to replace the part where it copies a specified range with a loop or filter that only copies the rows from each sheet that fit a criteria (in this case a column that has the values "yes" and "no" and I only want to copy the rows where it says yes and paste those into a consolidation sheet (RDBMergeSheet)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you tried to modify this code with a loop or filter to accomplish that?

Comment: Which rows/columns are you trying to copy once it matches this criteria? And where do you plan on pasting them once copied?

Comment: Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")   This code appears to only copy one row. What data did you want to copy?

Comment: Are you trying to do this? `Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G" & Last)`

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear I didnt modify this code much because I didnt know how to.. This is just some code I found which seems to accomplish part of what I want. I want istead of copying the range that is in the code to copy all rows from multiple sheets that have a certain criteria ( in this case a column that says "yes") and paste it into the RDBMerge Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question: I have an Excel Workbook consisting of multiple sheets that are all structured the same. I want to consolidate all the Data where in Column 238 it says "Yes" to a summary worksheet.

Ans: 
It seems like it would be a much easier task to remove rows that don't have the yes cell. That is after compiling all the sheets. So assuming you have compiled all rows and columns from each sheet in the summary sheet.

```
Sub Delete_all_non_yes()
  Sheets("Summary").Select
  Dim checked_cell As Integer
  Dim NB_rows As Integer
  ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
  NB_rows = ActiveCell.Row
  Dim Checked_cell_value As String
  checked_cell = 1
  Do While checked_cell <= NB_rows
    Checked_cell_value = Cells(checked_cell, 278)
    If Not Checked_cell_value = "Yes" Then 
      'checks each row for the value "Yes"
       Rows(checked_cell).Delete
    Else
      checked_cell = checked_cell + 1
    End If

  Loop

End Sub
```

You can then use the same logic and delete any columns that you are looking for. 
There are plenty of more efficient ways, but this should get the job done.

Note: my first stackoverflow Ans! Feedback is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will try to implement your solution!